# How do I rename a file based on string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code to rename a file with hardcoded file names.  Of course the date can change.

```
import shutil 
# Source path 
source = "C:\\WeeklyReports\\temp\\we mmddyy_DONE.xlsx"

# Destination path 
destination = "C:\\WeeklyReports\\we 101219.xlsx"

# Copy the content of 
# source to destination 
shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

How do I replace mmddyy in the source filename (we mmddyy_DONE.xlsx) with string format_mmddyy as shown below?

```
format_mmddyy
'100619'

type(format_mmddyy)
str
```

Comment: `new_text = text.replace("mmddyy",  "100619")`

Comment: use string formatting `f'{my_variable}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.replace` function

```py
import shutil 
# Source path 
source = "C:\\WeeklyReports\\temp\\we mmddyy_DONE.xlsx"
format_mmddyy = 100619
destination = source.replace('mmddyy_DONE', format_mmddyy)

shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```